# MongoDB Atomic transaction over multiple Databases

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, transactions

I have a single service that updates two databases. I want the have the operations on these databases to be atomic, if it fails then it will roll back on both databases.

The Databases I am using is mongoDB, the two databases are on two different clusters.

I have the following implementation:

```js
const db1Session = await db1.startSession();
const db2Session = await db2.startSession();
try {
    db1Session.startTransaction();
    db2Session.startTransaction();
        
    // perform operation on db1
    // perform operation on db2

    db1Session.commitTransaction();
    db2Session.commitTransaction();
} catch (error) {
    await db1Session.abortTransaction();
    await db2Session.abortTransaction();
    throw error;
}
```

I am not sure if this is a reliable way to implement the transaction. What is the recommend way to handle this in mongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You should generally prefer [Callback API to Core API](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/transactions-in-applications/#callback-api) because they internally handle some errors like `TransientTransactionError`.
This means that, instead of calling `start/commit/abortTransaction()`, you may want to use `withTransaction(callback)`. You can see some examples in the documentation.

In your case, you have two connections and, consequently, two sessions with the respective transactions. This means that, with the Callback APIs, you would have something like:

```
async function executeTransaction(session1, session2) {
    return await session1.withTransaction(async s1 => {
        const innerTrxResult = await session2.withTransaction(async s2 => {
            // transaction operations
        });

        if (innerTrxResult)
            console.log("inner transaction ok")
        else
            await session1.abortTransaction()
    })
}

await db1.withSession(async session1 => {
    await db2.withSession(async session2 => {
        const trxResult = await executeTransaction(session1, session2)

        if (trxResult)
            console.log("transaction successful")
        else
            console.log("transaction aborted")
    });
})
```

I have not tested it, but I can certainly tell you that it is not 100% reliable. The problem with this solution is that you cannot guarantee the commit at the same time. So, the transaction could commit on `db1` but `db2` connection could fail immediately after.

There might be a way to synchronize the 2 MongoDB connections or somehow make the transaction distributed among many clusters, but I am pretty positive you do not have any option as for now. You have to accept the risk that that transaction may not be atomic.